# Setting PlotRange conditionally

Tags: plotting, attributes

I have several sets of data, and each set of data has a different scale (i.e., a different range of function values). I wish to plot each data set separately. I can do this using `Table`, `ListPlot`, and `Grid`:

```
(* Generate sample data for the purpose of this minimal working example. *)
xVals = N /@ Range[0, 5 Pi, Pi/100];
data = {Map[{#, 3.0*Sin[#]} &, xVals], (* data with "small" maximum y-value *)
   Map[{#, 10.0*Sin[# + Pi/10]} &, xVals], (* data with "small" maximum y-value *)
   Map[{#, 300.0*Cos[#]} &, xVals] (* data with "large" maximum y-value *)
   };

(* Find maximum y-value of each set of data. *)
dataMaxes = Map[Max[#[[All, 2]]] &, data];
Print["dataMaxes = ", dataMaxes];

(* ListPlot each set of data separately (i.e., data[[i]] where i is 1, 2, or 3);
use Grid[] to display the plots side by side. *)
Grid[{
  Table[
   ListPlot[data[[i]], Joined -> True, Frame -> True, 
    FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"},
    PlotRange -> All
    ]
   , {i, 1, Length[data]}]
  }]
```

> dataMaxes = {3.,10.,300.}

[image: plots without conditional PlotRange]

In the code above, I set `PlotRange -> All` inside `ListPlot`. But suppose I wish to set `PlotRange` *conditionally*.

Specifically, I wish to set `PlotRange -> 50.0` when the maximum y-value is greater than or equal to 50.0, and `PlotRange -> All` otherwise.

I thought I could accomplish this by using an `If` statement like `If[dataMaxes[[i]] >= 50, 50.0, All]`. But the following code generates an error:

```
(* METHOD 1: gives error *)
(* If dataMaxes[[i]] >= 50.0, use PlotRange -> 50.0; otherwise, use PlotRange -> All. *)
Grid[{
  Table[
   ListPlot[data[[i]], Joined -> True, Frame -> True, 
    FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"},
    PlotRange -> If[dataMaxes[[i]] >= 50, 50.0, All]
    ]
   , {i, 1, Length[data]}]
  }]
```

> Flatten::normal: Nonatomic expression expected at position 1 in Flatten[$Failed].

I thought that this error may have to do with placing the `If` statement directly in the option value for `PlotRange`, so I tried instead determining the option value before calling `ListPlot`. The following two methods work well:

```
(* METHOD 2: works *)
Grid[{
  Table[
   myPlotRange = If[dataMaxes[[i]] >= 50, 50.0, All];
   ListPlot[data[[i]], Joined -> True, Frame -> True, 
    FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"},
    PlotRange -> myPlotRange
    ]
   , {i, 1, Length[data]}]
  }]
```

[image: method two output]

```
(* METHOD 3: works *)
myPlotRanges = Map[If[# >= 50, 50.0, All] &, dataMaxes];
Grid[{
  Table[
   ListPlot[data[[i]], Joined -> True, Frame -> True, 
    FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"},
    PlotRange -> myPlotRanges[[i]]
    ]
   , {i, 1, Length[data]}]
  }]
```

[image: method three output]

**Why is it that Method 1 fails, but Methods 2 and 3 work?**  `PlotRange` has the attributes `Protected` and `ReadProtected`, but nothing else (including `HoldAll`):

```
Attributes[PlotRange]
```

> {Protected, ReadProtected}

Comment: Method 1 gives me no error in 13.2.1

Comment: The attributes of `ListPlot` are the governing ones, not those of `PlotRange`. However, they're not the issue. (Well, there isn't issue when I test, as I said.)

Answer (score 3):

I do not know if you know this or not, but with `Table` there is a trick where you can assign something to variable, followed by `;` and then use this variable in the rest of Table.  This variable will not show up in the `Table` output. Actually any code before the last `;` in the Table will not show up.

So you can simply do

```
dataMaxes = Map[Max[#[[All, 2]]] &, data];
Grid[{Table[z = If[dataMaxes[[i]] >= 50, 50.0, All]; 
   ListPlot[data[[i]], 
            Joined -> True, 
            Frame -> True, 
            FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}, 
            PlotRange -> z
           ], {i, 1, Length[data]}
        ]
      }
    ]
```

Or you can get rid of `dataMaxes` if you do not needed anywhere else, and just do

```
Grid[{Table[z = If[Max[data[[i, All, 2]]] >= 50, 50.0, All]; 
   ListPlot[data[[i]], 
           Joined -> True, 
           Frame -> True, 
           FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}, 
           PlotRange -> z
         ], {i, 1, Length[data]}
      ]
     }
    ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I will try to comment on why the other ones did not work soon. but For me, the above is the simplest solution.

**Update**

I just tried your Method 1 which you say gives error, but it worked for me. I am using V 13.2.1. So I do not know why it did not work for you.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

ps. The reason this trick works, is nothing really special. `Table` like `Do` and `For` and any other command in Mathematica, is actually a `Function`.

And as we all know, in Mathematica the output of function (its final return value) is the last expression which should not have `;` at the end.

Table is a function which returns the last expression after the last `;`. Its arguments are the range specifications you give `{i, 1, Length[data]}`

So a Table is really like this

```
 Table[code;morecode; finalResultWhichDependsOnTheIndexI,{i,1,10}]
```

so you can add `code` inside Table to help simplify things without it showing up in final result.